# Android App gets crashed because of com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView.<init>

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Crashlytic Crash Report - Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.TextView.getProcessName(TextView.java:10076)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:703)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:693)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java)
       at com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView.<init>(ReactTextView.java)
       at com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager.createViewInstance(ReactTextViewManager.java)
       at com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager.createViewInstance(ReactTextViewManager.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.access$000(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:798)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:571)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: Please show us your code. It is otherwise impossible for us to help you

Comment: Its a crash report by crashlytics

Comment: It still comes from somewhere within your code. Some place that uses a ReactTextView

Comment: Yes thats true but its really difficult to reproduce this crash

Comment: ReactTextView is a java file from android side which causing this crash